# How to select a printer's tray in Nodejs (Electron)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, electron

I want to print mostly pdf files but therefore I need to select the correct printer's tray. I tried to get the printer's tray using different packages via npm. The only package I found which retrieves such information is `ipp` but my printer is not supporting this protocol. Is there any package which provides such feature: printing files in selected trays?

Comment: @KJ Do you know whether there is a function returning all trays of a printer?